# Showing $3^x+5^x$ is injective

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

How can we show that
$$f(x)=3^x+5^x$$
is injective?

I know that $f$ is strictly increasing in $R$ so $f(x) = k, k \in R$ has only one root.

But I was looking for a proper proof, something I tried was:

Let $x,y \in \mathbb R$. Then for $f$ to be injection, $$3^{x}+5^{x} = 3^{y}+5^{y}$$ must imply that $x=y$.

Now how do we proceed?

Comment: By showing that $3^x + 5^x$ is strictly increasing! That _is_ a proper proof,

Comment: yeah @quasi is there other method or this method is fine?

Comment: You can't beat it! Short and simple (and a reusable method).

Comment: What is "a proper proof"?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I am sorry I meant using the definition of injection

Comment: A strictly increasing function is by definition injective...

Comment: Actually, a strictly increasing function is not "by definition injective", but by proof.

Comment: Ok but we cannot use the other definition of injective here? [Proving_that_functions_are_injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function#Proving_that_functions_are_injective)

Comment: You _can_ (as egreg's answer shows), but the most _natural_ proof is by way of showing that $3^x + 5^x$ is increasing.

Comment: @akhmeteni The direct way of proving injectivity is hard for a lot of functions where the increasing property is much easier.

Comment: Thank you quasi and Thomas Andrews for showing the way!

Comment: Note:  $A \implies B$ is equivalent to $\lnot B \implies \lnot A$.  So prove if $x \ne y \implies 3^x + 5^x\ne 3^y + 5^y$.  If $x \ne y$ then either $x < y$ or $y < x$.  And...... $3^x + 5^x$ is strictly increasing!

Comment: @fleablood Thank you for making it simple!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not restrictive to assume $x\ge y$. If $t=x-y$, we have
$$
3^y(3^t-1)+5^{y}(5^t-1)=0
$$
Since $t\ge0$, also $3^t-1\ge0$ and $5^t-1\ge0$.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the basic properties of exponential functions:

- an exponential function of the form $a^x$ ($a>1$) is strictly increasing;
- the sum of two strictly increasing functions, is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)$ is injective means $f(x) = f(y) \iff x = y$.

So if you can show $x \ne y \implies f(x) \ne f(y)$ you are done.

Let $x < y$.  Then $y = x + k$ for some $k> 0$.  So $3^y = 3^{x+k} = 3^x\cdot 3^k$.  And $3^k > 1$ so $3^x3^k > 3^x$.  So $3^y > 3^x$.

By the same reasoning $5^y > 5^x$ and therefore $3^y + 5^y > 3^x + 5^y$.

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

Compute the derivative of $f(x)=\exp(x\ln(3))+\exp(x\ln(5)).$ Its derivative is $\ln(3)\exp(x\ln(3))+\ln(5)\exp(x\ln(5))>0.$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $3^x+5^x=3^y+5^y.$

Now $$3^x+5^x=3^y+5^y\Rightarrow 3^x-3^y=-(5^x-5^y)$$

Case 1: $x\geq y$, then $5^x-5^y\geq 0\Rightarrow 3^x-3^y=-(5^x-5^y)\leq 0$. But  $3^x-3^y\geq 0$. Which lead to  $3^x=3^y\Rightarrow x=y$

Case 2: $x\leq y$, then $5^x-5^y\leq 0\Rightarrow 3^x-3^y=-(5^x-5^y)\geq 0$. But  $3^x-3^y\leq 0$. Which lead to  $3^x=3^y\Rightarrow x=y$

Hence $3^x+5^x=3^y+5^y\Rightarrow x=y\space\space\space \blacksquare$

Comment: You need Case 1$x\geq y$ and Case 2$x\leq y$.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki yes, you are right!

Comment: Thank you too for solution!